# Имитировать нажатия Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pywin32

Нужно создать эмуляцию нажатия данных клавиш. Код с Shell не работает. Windows 11, Phyton 3.10.5.

```
import win32com.client

    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
    shell.SendKeys('^a')
```

Comment: вопрос-то в чем? пока это похоже не ТЗ. с ТЗ - не сюда.

Comment: и какие ожидания от этого кода? ну создаст он объект шелл, ну отправит в него какие-то кнопочки. в чем смысл?